# How can I update a WebView from within a TabHost?

Tags: android, webview, android-tabhost

Please forgive me if this answer is obvious, I am very new to Android but making steady progress.

I have searched exhaustively but fear I may be using the wrong terminology.

I have an Activity that creates a WebView:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

webviewHome = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webviewHome.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient1(){  
});
webviewHome.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webviewHome.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.3/codeholder.html");
```

The Activity also has a TabHost with 3 tabs:

```
//Tabs
tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

//Tab for Sky
TabSpec skyspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("0");
skyspec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sky));
Intent skyIntent = new Intent(this, sky.class);
skyspec.setContent(skyIntent);

//Tab for XBMC
TabSpec XBMCspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("1");
XBMCspec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xbmc));
Intent XBMCIntent = new Intent(this, xbmc.class);
XBMCspec.setContent(XBMCIntent);

//Tab for PC
TabSpec PCspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("2");
PCspec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.windows));
Intent PCIntent = new Intent(this, pc.class);
PCspec.setContent(PCIntent);

tabHost.addTab(skyspec);
tabHost.addTab(XBMCspec);
tabHost.addTab(PCspec);
```

The WebView and the tabs work fine. What I can't work out is how to send (for example) webviewHome.loadUrl("javascript:button('right')") from one of the tabs to the WebView without having to reload the Activity.

Your expertise would be appreciated...

Comment: SOLVED: It WAS simple. `public static WebView webviewHome;`. Then from other classes I can: `Home.webviewHome.loadUrl("javascript:button('up')");`